# How to select all records from a table by replacing values for two fields from other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image: DB Design]

This is the table design of an application I need to build. Kindly ignore the Role Table in the image.

Is there any method by which I can select all the records in the table transfer log , but instead of showing "User No" and "Plant No" in the result , I need to show the corresponding Employee No/Username from the user table and corresponding Plant Id from Plant Table.

Comment: Search for `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;)

```
select distinct
    log.LogNo, u.EmployeeNo/Username, p.PlantId, log.StartDate, log.EndDate, log.Active
from TransferLog log
left join UserTable u on u.UserNo = log.UserNo
left join PlantTable p on p.PlantNo = log.PlantNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join

```
select a.*, b.username, c.pantname
from transfer_log as a 
inner join User as b a.userno = b.userno
inner join plant as c a.plantno = c.plantno
```